# PDO SQL Query not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function in PHP:

```
function getFilteredList($conn, $limit, $offset, $job_app, $Job_Type, $location) {
    /*
    <option value="0">Select category or Search all</option>
    <option value="1">Business and Administration</option>
    <option value="2">Education and Training</option>
    <option value="3">Leisure, Travel and Tourism</option>
    <option value="4">Information and Communication Technology</option>
    */
    if($Job_Type == 1){
        $Job_Type2 = '%1%';
    }elseif($Job_Type == 2){
        $Job_Type2 = '%2%';
    }elseif($Job_Type == 3){
        $Job_Type2 = '%3%';
    }elseif($Job_Type == 4){
        $Job_Type2 = '%4%';
    }
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `jobs_current` WHERE `job_type` LIKE :job_type ORDER BY `jobs_current`.`job_comp_loc` ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ");
    $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':job_type', $Job_Type2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    $end = "";
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        if($row['job_app'] == $job_app){
            $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
        }else if($job_app == 0){
            $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
        }else{
            return '<td class="td1"></td><td class="td2" style="text-align: center;color: red;">Sorry, there doesnt seem to be any results!</td><td class="td3"></td>';
        }

    }
    return $end;
}
```

If i pass any parameters for the job_app it just returns 'Sorry, there doesn't seem to be any results!' Although there is results because some of the rows in fact have the job-app parameter in them. If i pass job_app as 2 and job_type as 2 it should come up with 6 results however it doesn't. Other parts of Relevent PHP:

DB List function:

```
function getGenericList($conn, $limit, $offset, $job_app) {

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `jobs_current` ORDER BY `jobs_current`.`job_comp_loc` ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ");
    $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

    $end = "";
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        if($row['job_app'] == $job_app){
            $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
        }else if($job_app == 0){
            $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
        }else{
            return '<td class="td1"></td><td class="td2" style="text-align: center;color: red;">Sorry, there doesnt seem to be any results!</td><td class="td3"></td>';
        }

    }
    return $end;
}
```

.php file that calls function:

```
$Job_Type = null;
$Location = null;
$Job_App = 0;
if(!$_GET['Job_App'] == null){
    $Job_App = $_GET['Job_App'];
}
if(!$_GET['Job_Type'] == null){
    if(!$_GET['Job_Type'] == 0){
        $Job_Type = $_GET['Job_Type'];
    }
}
if(!$_GET['Location'] == null){
    $Location = $_GET['Location'];
}
//irreleven stuff in between
if(!$_GET['page'] == null){
    $pageno = ($_GET['page']-1)*15;
    if(!$_GET['Job_Type'] == null){
        echo ''.getFilteredList($dbh, 15, $pageno, $Job_App, $Job_Type, $Location);
    }else{
        echo ''.getGenericList($dbh, 15, $pageno, $Job_App);
    }
}else{
    if(!$_GET['Job_Type'] == null){
        echo ''.getFilteredList($dbh, 15, 0, $Job_App, $Job_Type, $Location);
}else{
    echo ''.getGenericList($dbh, 15, 0, $Job_App);
}
}
```

Am i missing something to filter them properly? I have read through it myself a few times and it seems right but just doesn't filter as intended.

EDIT:

I didn't seem to make it clear enough, it does succeed with the query as it returns the end else statement in the while loop.

Comment: you can't, afaik, use placeholders in the `limit`, `order by` or `group by` clauses

Comment: @RamRaider I saw on here that you can only if you use pre-built strings there rather than dynamic ones.

Comment: I assume you have tried the query using phpMyAdmin or similiar to see what is produced

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i did, it did produce results, i have found the solution myself, i had to remake the function and filter them earlier on in the query

Answer (score 0):

You generate your error message in the `while` loop so you are definitely getting results:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if($row['job_app'] == $job_app){
        $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
        $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
        $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
    }else if($job_app == 0){
        $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
        $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
        $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
    }else{
        // Here you are in the while loop so you have results!
        return '<td class="td1"></td><td class="td2" style="text-align: center;color: red;">Sorry, there doesnt seem to be any results!</td><td class="td3"></td>';
    }
}
```

Your problem is that the `if` conditions don't match in any of the rows. You need to figure out why, for example by dumping the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction, i think i need to rebuild the SQL query so that i dont have to filter them that late

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function so that the job_app was filtered in the query rather than in a IF statement later on

```
function getFilteredList($conn, $limit, $offset, $job_app, $Job_Type, $location) {
    /*
    <option value="0">Select category or Search all</option>
    <option value="1">Business and Administration</option>
    <option value="2">Education and Training</option>
    <option value="3">Leisure, Travel and Tourism</option>
    <option value="4">Information and Communication Technology</option>
    */
    if($Job_Type == 1){
        $Job_Type2 = '%1%';
    }elseif($Job_Type == 2){
        $Job_Type2 = '%2%';
    }elseif($Job_Type == 3){
        $Job_Type2 = '%3%';
    }elseif($Job_Type == 4){
        $Job_Type2 = '%4%';
    }else{
        $Job_Type2 = '%1%2%3%4%';
    }
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `jobs_current` WHERE `job_type` LIKE :job_type AND `job_app` = :job_app ORDER BY `jobs_current`.`job_comp_loc` ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ");
    $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':job_app', $job_app, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':job_type', $Job_Type2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    $end = "";
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        if($row !== null){
            $end = $end.'<tr class="hoverOver"><td class="td1"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_comp_loc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td2"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['job_desc'].'</a></td>';
            $end = $end.'<td class="td3"><a   href="/jobview.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</a></td></tr>';
        }else{
            return '<td class="td1"></td><td class="td2" style="text-align: center;color: red;">Sorry, there doesnt seem to be any results!</td><td class="td3"></td>';
        }

    }
    return $end;
}
```

Comment: Note that you will never enter the loop when there are no rows. You need to check for the number of rows outside of the loop and return the error message if there are none.

Comment: @jeroen Ah thanks, i thought it entered it once if there was no results regardless, will update